# Unexpected token JavaScript

Tags: javascript

It is working fine on iPhone, iMac, Windows, but when I run it on an Android device, the following error is displayed in the console.

> Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token, pointing "window.onload = () =>{" this line of code.

```
/*
* Simple DOM test that collects the value from a textbox,
* and applies it to the header element by changing its color.
*/

window.onload= () =>{
    const myheading = document.getElementById('header');
    const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
    const bgColor = document.getElementById('bgColor');
    const textColor = document.getElementById('textColor');

    myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        myheading.style.color = 'black';
        bgColor.style.color = bgColor.value;
        textColor.style.color = textColor.value;

        if (bgColor.value === '' || textColor.value === '') {
            alert('Please enter color value');
            myButton.style.backgroundColor= "#f00";
            myButton.style.color = '#fff';
            myButton.innerHTML = 'Enter Color Name';

            setInterval(function() { 
                myButton.innerHTML = 'Change heading color';
                myButton.style.backgroundColor= "#dcdcdc";
                myButton.style.color = "black";
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            myheading.innerHTML = "You changed me into <u>" + textColor.value + "</u> with  a <u>"  + bgColor.value + "</u> background!";

            Object.assign(myheading.style, {
                padding: "10px",
                color: textColor.value,
                backgroundColor: bgColor.value
            });

            myButton.style.backgroundColor= "#fd1";
            myButton.innerHTML = 'Colors applied Success!';    
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That web browser evidently doesn't support arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **each** `()=>{` with `function(){`. The code will function the same and work on browsers that have not yet implemented arrow functions.

Since you are not using the `this` keyword in your onload function, there will be no difference in functionality (as arrow functions do not change scope while normal functions do). See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/3068233) for more details on the differences between normal functions and arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about the environment but about the browser supported version of Javascript. Arrows function is a feature available Javascript Ecmascript 6, [some browsers don't implement it, depending on their version](https://caniuse.com/#search=ES6).

In you case, you can just use Ecmascript 5 (ES5), replacing `() =>{}` by `function(){}`.

If you need ES6 functionnality on ES5 browsers, you may consider a compiler / polyfill.

Arrow functions are defined in [2015's version of ECMA-262 norm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions).